# Error 500 on push

Tags: git, http, bonobo

we are using the current version of Bonobo.
We set it up on Windows Server 2012 with  authentification.

Login etc. works fine. But if we want to push a commit we get an error code 500.

If i open the *.git URL in Chrome then i get the following error message:

> System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or
>   string. at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength) at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) at
>   Bonobo.Git.Server.GitAuthorizeAttribute.IsUserAuthorized(String
>   authHeader, HttpContextBase httpContext) at
>   Bonobo.Git.Server.GitAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext
>   filterContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList'1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)

Did anyone have an Idea??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be seeing [this](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/704) issue:

Do you know if there's a percentage sign in your password?